# How to add emerge --info to a bugreport with pybugz?

Tags: linux, gentoo, bugzilla

Users are usually requested to attach `emerge --info` to a bug report.

`bugz attach 501008 < (emerge --info)`

can create this system information in one line, but with a number as file name. Hence the browser can not determine how to display the file (MIME type).

How can I add it as `emerge--info.txt`?

A very dirty workaround is:

```
emerge --info > /tmp/emerge--info.txt && bugz attach 501008 /tmp/emerge--info.txt && rm /tmp/emerge--info.txt
```

Comment: Would explicitly specifying the content-type help? From a quick look at pybugz' source code, I can't even see how STDIN attach works.

Answer (score 0):

You can place it in a comment.